# Android: App engine NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am currently working on an app that uses app engine backend.  The following code crashes with

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.petfinder.backend.model.userApi.UserApi$Builder
```

I am stumped. I have tried updating all jars. Still no luck.

I can get this running on my Nexus 6 without error but when I run on other devices  like a Moto E the error crashes the app.

Testing on 4.4.4 device.

```
UserApi.Builder builder = new UserApi.Builder(AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport(),
            new AndroidJsonFactory(), null)
            // options for running against local devappserver
            // - 10.0.2.2 is localhost's IP address in Android emulator
            // - turn off compression when running against local devappserver
            //                        .setRootUrl("http://192.168.16.254:8080/_ah/api")
            .setRootUrl(URL)
            .setGoogleClientRequestInitializer(new GoogleClientRequestInitializer() {
                @Override
                public void initialize(AbstractGoogleClientRequest<?> abstractGoogleClientRequest) throws IOException {
                    abstractGoogleClientRequest.setDisableGZipContent(true);
                }
            });
```

Exception:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #2
        Process: com.petfinder.petfinder, PID: 17401

java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
     at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848)
  Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.petfinder.backend.model.userApi.UserApi$Builder
     at com.petfinder.petfinder.util.PetUtil.getUserApi(PetUtil.java:52)
     at com.petfinder.petfinder.ui.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:330)
     at com.petfinder.petfinder.ui.LoginActivity$UserLoginTask.doInBackground(LoginActivity.java:317)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
     at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:848) 
01-16 09:06:53.481 17401-17401/com.petfinder.petfinder D/ActivityThread: ACT-AM_ON_PAUSE_CALLED ActivityRecord{41dfff48 token=android.os.BinderProxy@
```

Comment: Please update your question with a stack trace of the error you are facing.

Answer (score 0):

Found the problem  was an out of date google play services.  Fixed it by checking for Google play services and updating the out of date device.

```
public void checkPlayServices() {
    int state = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);

    if (state == ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "SUCCESS", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    } else {
        Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(state, this, -1);
        dialog.show();
    }
}
```